# Do I have to create a new instance of fileinputstream if the file is changed constantly?

Tags: java, io, saxparser, fileinputstream

I have a xml log that is modified constantly by another application; however my Java code runs concurrently and checks for a couple of strings. I am using a SAX Parser. Now my question is will I have to have a new instance of a FileInputStream every time I loop through the file? How about the parser?

So let's say:

```
while(notfound)
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/tmp/123.xml"));
    SaxParser.parse(fis, sampleHandler);
    notFound = sampleHandler.checkIfFound();
}
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provided, you **will** need a new `FileInputStream` each time you want to start reading from the beginning of the file. `Stream` classes don't often allow for manual positioning/resetting of the 'location', as since the name ('Stream') implies, it's just a pipe with bits spewing out of it.

Since you're using the `SaxParser.parse()` class method to initiate the parsing, it doesn't seem as though you actually have a parser object to re-create. So you should be fine with just re-creating the `FileInputStream`.

But! It seems like current versions of the `SaxParser` class support passing in a `File` instance as the first parameter, so you can just repeatedly use:

```
while(notfound)
{
    SaxParser.parse(new File("c:/tmp/123.xml"), sampleHandler);
    notFound = sampleHandler.checkIfFound();
}
```

Avoiding the re-creation of the `FileInputStream` altogether, and allowing the parser to handle that.

Comment: Ah I see. Figured. Hmm let me try that out. Thanks a lot.